# Adding temporary field to form to print ID's

Tags: forms

When writing modules, especially in the "hook_form
_alter" hook, I find myself in the same situation many times:

I want to control some $form fields and I'm searching the field ID, the right attribute convention, etc.

I'm trying to print all the fields and their attributes to the output page so I could do that every time I need information about a form fields.

1. How can I print all the fields complete attributes?
2. I need to stick it temporarily in the page - how can I send the details to the page (I don't know what are the fields ID's...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) - Helper functions for Drupal developers and inquisitive admins.

Add in hook_form_alte function `dsm($form);` and refresh your form page, you will get message with structured info.